# Problema con ajax y jquery al mandar por post en un each el resultado me devuelve al final de recorrer cada fila

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Empecé recientemente a usar jquery y ajax, ahora estoy haciendo un proyecto y tengo el problema de que estoy tratando de recibir una id de una tabla principal para mandar devuelta y que me inserte en otra tabla que usa esa id como referencia.
 Entonces al insertarse en la tabla principal este devuelve su id que luego mando al servlet que hizo la inserción para que las siguientes inserciones usen esa id para insertar los siguientes datos en la tabla secundaria

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).on('click', '#boton', function() {
      var comprobante=0;
      $("#curso1 tr").each(function(){
          var bandera=0;      
      
          $(this).children('th').each(function(index){
          
              if ($(this).find("input").prop('checked')) {    //ve si la fila está marcada
                 alert("marcado");
                 bandera=1;
              }
    
          });
          //si está marcada entonces
          if (bandera===1) {
      
              var carrera=$("#carreras").val();
              var plan=$("#planes").val();
              var alumno=$("#Alumno").val();
              var materia=$(this).children('th').next('td').text().trim();
              alert(carrera+ " "+plan+" "+materia+" comprobante es "+comprobante);

              //inserta y devuelve el resultado
     
              $.post('Inscripcion',{
                  fcarrera: carrera,
                  fplan: plan,
                  fmateria: materia,
                  falumno:alumno,
                  findex:comprobante
              },
              function(resultado) {
                  alert("me devuelve al final "+resultado.map.idinscripcion);
                  //cambia comprobante para que al enviar no sea 0 y no se cree de nuevo la tabla principal
                  comprobante=resultado.map.idinscripcion;
                
              },
              'json'
              ); 

          }
       
      });
  }); 
</script>
```

Esta parte funciona perfecto solo que en lugar de insertar por post y devolver el resultado para cambiar la variable comprobante, este primero inserta cada fila de mi tabla y cuando termina de insertar cada cosa va cambiando la variable comprobante por cada id que se creo, lo que me gustaría resolver es que yo al insertar una fila ya realizara la función resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que propones únicamente funcionaría si las peticiones las realizaras de forma síncrona y no asíncrona, lo cual sería una muy mala práctica y nada óptimo.

Te recomiendo que no hagas un bucle y llamadas AJAX anidadas, hazlo de forma masiva. Si tienes todos los elementos pásalos todos mediante AJAX y haz el tratamiento que creas oportuno, no uno a uno.